# Conflict with dependency google Drive and Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got the below error after Sync gradle

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1)

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev94-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app `build.gradle` add:

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
```

Enforces Gradle to only compile the version number you state for all dependencies, no matter which version number the dependencies have stated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency for `2.0.1` manually. The conflict will be resolved. All the libraries dependent on `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305` will then use `2.0.1`.

`1.3.9` might not work because one of the dependencies needs a higher version.